# android sqlite deleting record being lined as foreign key with another record

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

I have the following tables in my sqlite android database:

```
CREATE TABLE MAIN (
_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
NAME TEXT,
.....
CURRENT_CARD INTEGER
FOREIGN KEY (CURRENT_CARD) REFERENCES CARD (_ID));

CREATE TABLE CARD (
_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
.....
```

Now I want to delete records from my CARD table in the following way:

```
DELETE FROM CARD WHERE _ID IN (10,11,12,...);
```

Everything works ok until I have the record in Card table being linked to Main table, ex. let's admit that Card with id 11 has the corresponding record in Main table. When deleting Card 11 I would like to set the corresponding CURRENT_CARD field for record ex. 1 in MAIN as null (I don't want to delete the whole record in MAIN, just to null one column).

How to do that in the easiest way? If possible as one sql statement...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ON DELETE SET NULL` action](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) with the `FOREIGN KEY`.

Remember to enable foreign key support with `pragma foreign_keys='ON'`.

Comment: Should I add this to Main table? The problem is that the program is already used by users, so can I alter the previously created table with ON DELETE SET NULL somehow?

Comment: You can migrate old data to a new table, drop the old table and rename the new.

Comment: You don't make me too happy, a lot of work... I'm wondering if perhaps there is any simpler solution....